# settimeout is blocking event-loop Nodejs check the next example:

Tags: javascript, node.js, real-time, scalability

Help me undertand.
This is the code:

```
var start = Date.now();

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(Date.now() - start);
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){}
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){}
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(Date.now() - start);
}, 2000);
```

When run this code in REPL or in a node server,the message that display is not the apropiate. The message that display are: 1000 and 3188 --> Here is the problem because this will be 1000,2000. Why the second console.log comand delay to execute?? How I can manage the Timers in nodejs??

IN NODEJS:
How I can make it if I need to trigger a task exactly 2 seconds before one first task, whitout matter the long of time of the first delay.

Comment: JavaScript is still single threaded. Your `for` loops take one second to finish, which delays the execution of the second `setTimeout` callback by the same amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript execution is still single-threaded in Node.js. As long as the `for` loops keep that thread busy, the 2nd `function` and the `console.log()` will have to wait.

John Resig has a good explanation of timers in "[How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)."

> How I can make it if I need to trigger a task exactly 2 seconds before one first task, whitout matter the long of time of the first delay.

You can move the longer-running, synchronous task (in this case, the `for` loops) into its own module and using [`child_process.fork()`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) to execute it.

```
// long-running.js

var start = Number(process.argv[2]);

for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){}
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){}

console.log('3', Date.now() - start);
```

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

var start = Date.now();

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('1', Date.now() - start);
    child_process.fork('./long-running', [start]);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('2', Date.now() - start);
}, 2000);
```

```
// output
1 1013
2 2016
3 3395
```

Comment: actually, in js the events store in a FIFO queue and execute one after another so if one event takes more time, it delays the next ones!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the code is not parallel and setTimeout function add code to the queue that will be executed when it can.

And the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) say that:

> delay is the number of milliseconds (thousandths of a second) that the
>   function call should be delayed by. The actual delay may be longer